# UI Automation Tool

Tags: .net, automation, ui-automation

Im new to Automation and I'm involved in developing an Automation Tool which can be used to Automate and Record all the current Process that are handled in a machine using `.NET`. Is it possible to automate all those process and thier controls using a Tool. 
Please help me with this. Please refer me some Tools which already doing this kind of work.

Comment: My question is that creating a tool like "White" for detecting the applications that are currently opened in ur machine, get the events of any of those application by clicking on the controls, recording those actions and automating the application.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to automate your tests on your application, rather than 'developing a Automation Tool'. That said, you should be able automate your application (web/windows/swing/...). There are many tools out in the market. [Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/test-professional/overview), [TestComplete](http://smartbear.com/products/qa-tools/automated-testing/), Quick Test Professional are some of the commercial tools. For open source tools, you can check [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), [Watin](http://watin.org/) (for .NET) , [Watir](http://watir.com/) (for Ruby).

Comment: Actually I have to develop a Automation Tool. Earlier we have a tool that can only automate our Company's Applciation. Since it was good, they want us to develop a tool which can automate and record test controls for all the applications.

Comment: In the first place, I'm not sure why you would need to develop such a tool, when there are plenty of them available in the market. Not sure, whether I understand your question. Can you please be more elaborate on your question, like what kind of application (web/windows), what actions do you want to automate, etc. If you want to develop a tool similar to the tools that I specified above, then I think you may have to look int C++ API - to my knowledge, it is not possible in .NET (though you may be able to capture key strokes and mouse movements, it will be hard to get the UI elements, etc...)

Comment: We are planning to do it in Windows applciation. The plan is to automate every controls like button clicks, adding and updating datas, automating custom controls etc., Like whatever you do on an application, it has to be reflected as a script in my tool.